# fixing textrelocation library

Tags: android, relocation

I have a very important android native library which has text relocation problems.
I have developed one android project using this library. It works well on Android devices which have Android OS version before 6.0, but this project is not working on Android 6.0 and above devices.

Is there a way to fix the library without source code?

Comment: If a library isn't open source, you most possibly are also not allowed to edit it. Are you sure it isn't a bug? If you explain you problem a bit more in detail, we might be able to you.